# Условный оператор if

Tags: c

Почему при входных данных n = 31 и m = 2 на выходе имею "correct", тогда как я ставлю условие, при котором "correct" должно быть на выходе, только если n <=29 ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void) { 
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    int n,m;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);

    if ((m == 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12) && (n <= 31)){
            printf("correct");
        } 
        else 
        if ((m == 4 || 6 || 9 || 11) && (n <=30)){
            printf("correct");
        } 
        else 
        if ((m == 2) && (n <=29)){
            printf("correct");
        }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`m == 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12` - всегда истина, потму что 3 - истина. Скорее всего вы имели в виду. `m == 1 || m == 3 || m == 5 || m == 7 ...`